# Pipeline Server Eval not returning appropriately

Tags: bash

I am fairly new to bash and have been asked to develop a pipeline process for use on gitlab. I have simplified my variable notation below. My problem is that a command that runs fine locally will not run correctly on the server.

I have a dynamically generated $command_string that looks something like this:

```
command_string="cf service-key ${val1} ${val2}"
```

Locally, I can run 
`new_var=$(eval ${command_string})`

But when this command is submit to the server and run as a pipeline, it breaks.

I should note that when I remove the new_var definition as the output of the eval function, it seems to run.  The problem is that I need the output information so that I can extract information from the output.

Additionally, I have tried `new_var=$(bash -c ${command_string})` but this returns a value as if I had submit only the first "cf" portion of $command_string (i.e. it returns the help menu of the cf function rather than the output of the provided arguments).

As I said, bash is a new language for me so I am sure I am missing something fundamental here.

Answer (score 1):

`${val1}` and `${val2}` are expanded at the time of definition, not evaluation, which means that the use of `command_string` will not be "dynamic" as you intend.

Consider defining a function as follows:

```
my_command ()
{
    cf service-key "$1" "$2"
}
```

and using the function within your code as

```
new_var=$(my_command "$val1" "$val2")
```

. The `eval` is unnecessary since the `$(...)` is a command substitution which evaluates the contents of the enclosed command.

Comment: The $command_string in your first point was a typo on my part. My code correctly defined the command_string.

I did try removing the eval and just using service_key=$("$command_string") but that returned an error "cf service-key... : command not found".  So I am trying your first solution in defining a function.  I'll get back to you

Comment: Well, I have created the my_cf function and using echo's I have successfully passed the variables into the function but now it is failing somewhere in the middle:
`echo starting my cf`
`my_cf "$var1" "$var2"`
`echo made it out of my_cf`

The second echo never triggers.  This is probably a different issue than my original post now, though.  I'll keep working on it.  Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Try putting some `echo`s in the function itself to see if the variables are getting through and to see how far it gets before exiting.